Databricks path
I'm trying to access a file located in the same folder I'm working in, and I get the FileNotFoundError.
My file call is:
with open('/dfbs/Workspace/Groups/MyFolder/MyFile.py', 'r') as fgc:
    output = fgc.readlines()

And the error is:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dfbs/Workspace/Groups/MyFolder/MyFile.py'

I tried several variants of the path but with no luck.
Can someone guide me on the right way to invoke a path in Databricks?
